# Wordpress & Angular: How to get data from another page with page ID

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I am quite new to Angular, but I have successfully set up a list.html template to show posts in Wordpress using V2 of the WP API.
Now, I would like to show some (ACF) fields from another page above my post list. I have the ACF API plugin installed as well, and it does work for posts.

I just have no idea how to refer to the right page ID, or if I need to set up another controller for this.

```
<!-- try to get data out of page id 2 > http://www.example.com/wp-json/acf/v2/page/2 -->
<h1 ng-bind-html="pages:2.acf.title">not working...yet...</h1>
```

As you can see ":2" probably makes no sense, but I could not find any reference on how to do this properly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

btw. this is the full code from my list.html template/partial:

```
<!-- try to get data out of page id 2 > http://www.example.com/wp-json/acf/v2/page/2 -->
<h1 ng-bind-html="pages:2.acf.title">not working...yet...</h1>



<div class="post-list">
    <article ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'date'"  class="col-md-2">
        <div>
            <div class="date-wrap">
                <h6 class="event-date">{{post.title.rendered}}</h6>
            </div>
            <!-- <div ng-bind-html="post.content.rendered | to_trusted"></div> -->
            <div ng-if="post.acf.event_title">

            <div class="post-data-container">
                <p>{{post.acf.event_title}}</p>
                <p ng-if="post.acf.conversation_with">A conversation with {{post.acf.conversation_with}}</p>
                <p>{{post.acf.about_or_by}} {{post.acf.lecture_from}} </p>
            </div>
                <img ng-src="{{post.acf.portrait.sizes.thumbnail}}" />
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!post.acf.event_title">No Event Title</div>
            <a ui-sref="detail({id: post.id})">Click here to read more</a>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to add that I don't HAVE to use ng-bind-html. It could also be something like: `<h1>{{pageID.acf.title}}</h1>`

Comment: can you share your html code, are you using a ng-repeat to iterate over the index items?

Comment: I would create a ctrl function to call your [api](http://www.example.com/wp-json/acf/v2/page/2), store it in a variable on the `$scope.dataFromApi` and use it in your view `{{dataFromApi}}`.

Comment: Thanks, Jax, I will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you grabbing the ACF data from the **OTHER** post? Is it part of your JSON object that returns to the view? If it is, you would just point to that. To verify it is, go to yourdomain.com/posts/:id where id is the post you are viewing, and see if the OTHER post's ACF data is present.

If not you'll need to create a controller or another function which hits the API again for that other post's data, so $scope.other_post = getPost({id:OtherPostID});

make sense?

Comment: Makes good sense indeed. This seems to be the answer I can work with. Thanks a lot, Roy!

Comment: This is how I eventually set up my controller: `wpApp.controller( 'ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Posts', 'Pages', function( $scope, Posts, Pages ) {
 console.log('ListCtrl');

 // $scope.post_title = Posts.get({ID:41});

 $scope.page_two = Pages.get({ID:2});


 Posts.query(function( res ) {
  $scope.posts = res;
 });
 
}]);`